# WPF DataGrid Custom Template auto generated column content binding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

so I've got a datagrid whose SourceItem structure is unknown, but needs a tiny tweak... i'm using AutoGenerateColumns but for one of the data types I override with my own column using the dg_AutoGeneratingColumn event wherein I check the e.PropertyType and override the e.Column with my new ColumnTemplate (inherits from DataGridBoundColumn).

Generally speaking it executes and renders fine, except that i'm trying to get the data binding (path is unknown) to flow into my custom ColumnTemplate.

```
CustomTemplate : DataGridBoundColumn
{
    public static DependencyProperty dpblah;
    private void MyCode() { GetValue(dpBlah); }
}

DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(...) {
    var oldBinding = (e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding;
    e.Column = new CustomTemplate { Header = e.PropertyName };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(e.Column, dpBlah, oldBinding);
}
```

everything seems to run, but when MyCode() runs, GetValue has nothing.

Is there something I'm missing? Why can't I get the value from the binding?

Comment: What target property in the template are you trying to bind to?

Comment: @mm8 the target is my custom dpBlah

Comment: @mm8 binding.Source comes from whatever the datagrid assigns automatically... though i'm thinking i perhaps need to assign the context in case it's not inherited

Comment: @mm8 realized I mistyped (edited the original post)... SetBinding passes in the oldBinding that the datagrid sets up automatically

Comment: How does CustomTemplate generate the cell contents? How do you intend to use the binding? The built-in columns generates elements and apply the binding to these.

Comment: @mm8 the CustomTemplate.GenerateElement (one of the two required methods to implement DataGridColumn from which DataGridBoundColumn inherits) adds the controls... that part all works fine, they render correctly... in my case the binding / data values are not used visually, but rather in processing commands/etc.

Comment: So you want to set the value of the `dpblah` property to the *value or the path* of the source property in your `AutoGeneratingColumn` event handler?

Comment: all said and done, all i care about is the value... in theory it seems the right thing to do is to assign the binding to dpBlah and then GetValue during the processing... but in practice I don't care, and I can just evaluate the binding during the dg_AutoGenerateColumns and set it to a non-DP/non-INPC field/property.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your property to the path of the binding and then use this path when you create the visual elements in your `CustomTemplate` class:

```
var oldBinding = (e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn).Binding as Binding;
e.Column = new CustomTemplate { Header = e.PropertyName, dpblah = oldBinding?.Path?.Path; };
```

In `CustomTemplate`, you could then get the value of the property for a specific item using reflection, e.g.:

```
protected override FrameworkElement GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, object dataItem)
{
    string bindingPath = dpblah;
    object value = dataItem.GetType().GetProperty(bindingPath).GetValue(dataItem);
    ...
}
```

If `dataItem` is a `DataRowView` you don't have to use reflection:

```
DataRowView drv = dataItem as DataRowView;
if(drv != null)
{
    object value = drv[bindingPath];
}
```

Comment: dataItem.GetType.GetProperty(bindingPath) returns null... dataitem is datarowview

Comment: for what it's worth, it appears that *somewhere*, and i'm not sure where, I get a binding error - "Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=colName; DataItem=null"... after the AutoGeneratingColumn handler, after the CustomTemplate.GenerateElement method... guessing it may have something to do with how datagrids aren't in the visual tree, but I don't see anything different from the MSFT code (using dotPeek to dig into DataGrid, TextColumn, etc)

Comment: @ScottBrickey: If `dataItem` is a `DataRowView` you don't have to use reflection. Please see my edit.

Comment: @ScottBrickey: Did you try this?